# My python/sklearn/SVM is running endlessly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, mnist

Hi I'm trying to train MNIST classifier with SVM(SVC), sci-kit learn(sklearn).
But my training runs endlessly.. What should I do?

I tried changing parameters of SVC but I'm not sure about what I'm doing
And It doesn't work...

The number of training data is 60,000
Please help me

```py
    import os
    import struct
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib .pyplot as plt

    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

    def read(dataset = "training", path="."):
      if dataset is "training":
        fname_img = os.path.join(path, 'train-images-idx3-ubyte.idx3-ubyte')
        fname_lbl = os.path.join(path, 'train-labels-idx1-ubyte.idx1-ubyte')
      elif dataset is "testing":
        fname_img = os.path.join(path, 't10k-images-idx3-ubyte.idx3-ubyte')
        fname_lbl = os.path.join(path, 't10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.idx1-ubyte')
      else:
        raise Exception("dataset must be 'testing' or 'training'")
      with open(fname_lbl, 'rb') as flbl:
          magic, num = struct.unpack(">II", flbl.read(8))
          lbl = np.fromfile(flbl, dtype=np.int8)

      with open(fname_img, 'rb') as fimg:
        magic, num, rows, cols = struct.unpack(">IIII", fimg.read(16))
        img = np.fromfile(fimg, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(len(lbl), rows, cols)

      get_img = lambda idx: (lbl[idx], img[idx])

        # Create an iterator which returns each image in turn
      for i in range(len(lbl)):
        yield get_img(i)

    tr = list(read("training", "/content/gdrive/My Drive/ColabNotebooks/MNIST"))
    tst = list(read("testing", "/content/gdrive/My Drive/ColabNotebooks/MNIST"))

    def seperate(data):
      labels =[]
      images =[]
      for i in data:
        labels.append(int(i[0]))
        images.append(i[1])
      return {"labels":labels, "images":images}

    train = seperate(tr)
    test = seperate(tst)

    clf = SVC(kernel = 'linear', cache_size = 6000, gamma = 0.001, C = 100)
    train_len = len(tr)
    train_Array = np.array(train["images"]).reshape(train_len, -1)


    clf.fit(train_Array, train["labels"])
```

Comment: "For large datasets consider using sklearn.linear_model.LinearSVC" - from  sklearn SVC's doc

Comment: Oh LinearSVM works! Thank you